# IIS: add binding to Default Web Site

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-manager

I just started looking at IIS on Windows10.

I have a stupid question. I added a binding to Default Web Site ("www.test.com") in  IIS Manager.

I was expecting to see the default page when browsing to this url, but it took me instead to an actual existing page.

Can anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

If you've added www.test.com to your bindings, clients (like your web browser on the same system) still don't know that IIS hosts the site.

see this: [Setting up a Host File - Faking URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165979/setting-up-a-host-file-faking-urls)

This is useful when dealing with multiple sites:

Site 1:

- test.com
- www.test.com
- www2.test.com

Site 2:

- another.url.com

with just listening to a single IP, you cannot control which request ends up at which site, this is what the binding solves

Comment: So what's the point of adding a binding?
I mean I could have set up just the host file to have the same result, right?

Comment: For a single site you are right, but if you have many websites, with bindings you can control which site listens to which urls: